# How to fix this error: Controller method not found in laravel?

Tags: laravel

NotFoundHttpException in Controller.php line 269: Controller method not found.

The original before submitting the form: http://localhost/framework_freshway/public_html/home/setting

soulfy/setting.blade.php

```
   <li>
                                <form action="../home/setting" method="post">
                                <span class="setting-name">MENU CSS</span>
                                <!-- <form method="POST" action="/posts"> -->
                                {{ csrf_field() }}  
                                <span class="setting-value center"> 
                                <select name="cars">
                                    <option value="red">Red</option>
                                    <option value="blue">Green</option>
                                    <option value="green">Orange</option>
                                    <option value="orange">Yellow</option>
                                    <option value="orange">Blue</option>
                                    <option value="orange">Black</option>
                                    <option value="orange">White</option>
                                    <option value="orange">Grey</option>
                                </select>
                                <!-- <div style="width: 150px; height: 30px;">        <input type="image" src="http://localhost/framework_freshway/public_html/images/submit.png" value="SUBMIT" width="10"> -->
                                <input type="submit" value="Submit"> 
                                </span>                                         
                                <br><br><br>    

                                </form>

                            </li>
```

After pressing the submit button it goes to this url:

http://localhost/framework_freshway/public_html/home/setting

NotFoundHttpException in Controller.php line 269: Controller method not found.

```
Route::post('/', [
'uses' => 'SettingController@getMenu'
]);

Route::controllers([
 'auth' => 'Auth\AuthController',
 'password' => 'Auth\PasswordController',
 'home'=>'HomeController',
 'member'=>'MemberController',
 'mail'=>'MailController',
 'social'=>'SocialController',
 'ajax'=>'AjaxController',
 'api'=>'ApiController',
 'timeline'=>'TimelineController',
 'setting'=>'SettingController',
 'ecommerce'=>'EcommerceController',
 'test'=>'TestController',
]);
```

Comment: route not defined  Route::post('/home/setting', 'SettingController@getMenu');

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your server is running a few levels higher that it should.

Start your server in the root directory of your app

The route should be `http://localhost/home/setting`

The `home/setting` will then be the route that is matched in your web.php route file.

So in that route file you need a route like `Route::post('home/setting', <controller@method> )`

see 
https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/routing#basic-routing 
for more information

HTH

Answer (score 0):

Your Form action should be like this:-

```
<form action="{{ url('/home/setting') }}" method="post">
                   or
<form action="{{ action('SettingController@getMenu')}}" method="post">
```

And try this route:-

```
Route::post('/home/setting', 'SettingController@getMenu');
```

Hope it helps !